# Docs needed to read before submitting app to App Store

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, development

What are the documents one has to read before submitting an app to the App Store?

I guess these are the two:

- [App review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html)
- [iOS human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Are there others?

Answer (score 2):

Since Apple has a review process, you might just submit your app and react if there are problems in review. Also, you might want to be sure you've read all the terms and conditions of the NDA / legal agreement that was signed to become a developer in addition to the links you provide.